# How to change underline color of <Select/> by setting classes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

```
const styles = {
 inkbar: {
  '&:after': {
   backgroundColor: 'red',
   height: '2px'
 }
},
 underline:{
 '&:before':{
  height:'2px',
  backgroundColor:'green'
}
}
};

  <Select
      fullWidth
      value={this.props.value}
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
      input={
        <Input
          classes={{    
            inkbar:this.props.classes.inkbar,
            underline:this.props.classes.underline}}
        />
      }
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </Select>)
```

But when I check code with react tool, I found the classes of `<Input>` component did not change. Does anyone know how to change the color of inkbar and underline in `<Select>` component?

I use Material-ui v1.0.0-beta

---

I have soloved by setting className. But I still want to know why changing classes does not work.

Comment: change the keywrod 'classes' to 'style' (to the component Input)

Comment: Tip : To disable underline completely - `<Select disableUnderline>` https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18329#issuecomment-553106570 . I stumbled on this question while looking for ways to disable underline, someone else may too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `classes` use `className` , for more information checkout this [link](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selects/#selects)

Comment: classes is the prop provided by the component. https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/oql16nn046 go to demo.js and search for  className={classes.selectEmpty} you will find what i mean, u have just edited the post and marked it as solved :)

Comment: yea I change to use className so I edited my post. But I am still confused. both classes and className can override and I dont understand why classes do not work this time.

Comment: When the className property isn't enough, and you need to access deeper elements, you can take advantage of the classes property to customize all the CSS injected by Material-UI for a given component, for example of the Button in MaterialUI "OverridesClasses" is using Button's classes prop to provide an array containing the names of classes to override (keys), and the CSS class names to apply (values). The component's existing classes will continue to be injected, so it is only necessary to provide the specific styles you wish to add or override.

Comment: here is another link to understand what hes doing in material ui [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/2187047q5p) , go to demo.js and see how hes setting the OverridesClasses

Comment: I usually use classes to override and it works fine.  I just cant use it in `<Select
      fullWidth
      value={this.props.value}
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
      input={
        <Input
          classes={{    
            inkbar:this.props.classes.inkbar,
            underline:this.props.classes.underline}}
        />
      }
    >`

Comment: can u give me an example how are u using classes (and it works)? compare the two components and u will find what i mean , i really cannot answer for the next 4 hours so it will take a little bit of time sorry :)

Comment: in your example TextField component will be compared by Select component , in the TextField your passing the classes under the InputLabelProps property and not to the TextField ,  i guess this help :) i will really appreciate setting the answer as correct , i recommand u reading the documentation of material-ui to more understand , here the TextField as an example https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/

Comment: in Select I posted in question I tried to pass classes to Input, but it pass to Select actuallly,  I dont know why it pass to Select instead of Input.  thanks anyway~

Comment: u are right u are setting the classes to the input component , All the components accept a classes property to customize the styles in material ui . i guess it will work too when you use classes under inputProps , but my advice to you, for styling always use the className property if its not enough use classes , here is the api of input in material ui https://material-ui-next.com/api/input/, is it clear to you right now ? :)